# how to populate nested form array in table in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects and inside each object i have array of objects. I wanted to populate those inside array of objects(checklist and weightage) into table.What i get is , I could populate the array of object and inside array is not displaying with each rowspan.
Attached my output and expected output image
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uUme.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqYtD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqVjs.png

```
HTML code;
     <table class="table table-xs table-sm table-hover">
    <thead class="table-primary">
    <tr>
    <th width="20%">Activity Name</th>
    <th width="15%">Activity Description</th>
    <th width="15%">Overall Percentage</th>
    <th width="10%">CheckList</th>
    <th width="10%">Weightage</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ng-container formArrayName="activity_mappings" *ngFor="let activity of activityMappings['controls']; let i = index;">
     <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
     <tr>
       <td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Activity Name"
     formControlName="activity_name"/>
       </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Description"
     formControlName="description"/>
      </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Overall Percentage"
     formControlName="overall_percentage"/>
     </td>
      <ng-container formArrayName="check_lists" *ngFor="let ch of activity.check_lists;let checkListindex = index;">
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="checkListindex">
    <ng-container *ngIf="checkListindex > 0">
     <td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="CheckList" formControlName="check_list_title"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text"  formControlName="weightage" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Weightage"/>
    </td>
    </ng-container>
     </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
     </tr>
    </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tr *ngIf="activityMappings.length == 0">
      <td class="text-center" colspan="4">No Activities Found</td>
       </tr>
           </tbody>
     </table>
```

[data population to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uUme.png)

**sample object:**

```js
activity_mappings ": [ { "
activity_name ": "
testing ", "
description ": "
som text ", "
overall_percentage ": 80, "
check_lists ":[ { "
check_list_title ": "
Done ", "
weightage ": "
20 " } ] }, { "
activity_name ": "
playing ", "
description ": "
some text ", "
overall_percentage ": 30, "
check_lists ":[ { "
check_list_title ": "
Not Done ", "
weightage ": "
30 " } ] } ]
```

Comment: can you rephrase your description? Also, instead of the image can you add an actual array of objects for ease.

Comment: "activity_mappings": [
    {
      "activity_name": "testing",
      "description": "som text",
      "overall_percentage": 80,
      "check_lists":[
          {
              "check_list_title": "Done",
              "weightage": "20"
          }
      ]
    },
 {
      "activity_name": "playing",
      "description": "some text",
      "overall_percentage": 30,
      "check_lists":[
          {
               "check_list_title": "Not Done",
              "weightage": "30"
          }
      ]
    }
  ] just wanted to populate this array of objects to table sir

Comment: Also, can you add you working here https://stackblitz.com/ for easy debugging

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cosfai?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your checklist is not a FormArray, so first change the line when create the formArray

```
 activityAuditMappings(obj?) {
    return this.fb.group({
      ...
      check_lists: this.fb.array(this.loopchecklist(obj)) //<--use this.fb.array
    });
```

As always you use a FormArray we need a getter of the FormArray. When we use a FormArray inside a FormArray we can not use a getter else a simple function that need an index

```
  getCheckListMappings(index:number): FormArray  {
    return this.activityMappings.at(index).get('check_lists') as FormArray
  }
```

That you can use like

```
          <ng-container formArrayName="check_lists"
            *ngFor="let ch of getCheckListMappings(i).controls;let checkListindex = index;">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="checkListindex">
              <ng-container *ngIf="checkListindex > 0">
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="CheckList"
          readonly="true"  formControlName="check_list_title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text"  formControlName="weightage" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Weightage" readonly="true" />
                </td>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
```

Really I imagine you want to create a table inside a td to allow change the values of checkList

```
  <tbody>
    <ng-container formArrayName="activity_mappings">
      <tr style="vertical-align:top" *ngFor="let activity of activityMappings['controls']; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Activity Name"
            formControlName="activity_name" readonly="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Description"
            formControlName="description" readonly="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Overall Percentage"
            formControlName="overall_percentage" readonly="true" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <table style="border-collapse: collapse;border:0" formArrayName="check_lists">
            <tr *ngFor="let ch of getCheckListMappings(i).controls;let checkListindex = index;"
              [formGroupName]="checkListindex">
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="CheckList"
          readonly="true"  formControlName="check_list_title"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text"  formControlName="weightage" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Weightage" readonly="true" />
              </td>
          </table>
          <ng-container *ngIf="getCheckListMappings(i).controls.length == 0">
            No Activities Found
          </ng-container>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
```

You can see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g78wco?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)